# Will a Mat pointer be automatically released when being reassigned or as an ROI, source Mat is released?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, mat

I'm trying to understand clearly how Mat (OpenCV) works in many specific cases. The cases I'm inquiring in this post are the following:

1. When a Mat pointer is reassigned to other location, will the previous header and data memory be freed automatically? for example:

   ```
   Mat *m = XXX;
   m = YYY;
   ```
2. If I call sourceMat.release(), does it also release the header m?

   ```
   Mat m = sourceMat(Rect);
   ```

Comment: Quick answer: never use Mat pointers! Create always Mats on the stack, and internal reference counting will do the rest (and thus you never need to use release)

Comment: And for your 1st question, what are `XXX` and `YYY`? If they are `cv::Mat`, it should be `Mat *m = &XXX` and `m = &YYY` instead.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Miki : the case is that the Mat instance will be available in main function. Everytime assigning the instance to another Mat constructor, for example MatInstance = sourceMat1(Rect1); and then MatInstance = sourceMat2(Rect2)...;, will the instance only be changed its elements' value and data pointer but is its address not changed at all?

Comment: @0nand0n I don't understand what you're asking, sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Miki : So as I understand, using Mat is safer since the header only changes its components' values, like cols, rows,... and maybe data pointer? But I still see people using pointer for Mat. Is the reason because copying address only is faster than copying the whole header? if yes, is that difference in copying time worthy?

Comment: @0nand0n (disclaimer: personal opinion) if you see peolple using Mat pointers, you should tell them they are very very wrong. Mats use shallow copy (copy the header only) so it's just a few microseconds slower than copying a pointer, but will keep reference counter consistency. Using pointers will surely cause memory leaks (besides others errors) in something more complex than a "hello world" program.

Comment: @Miki: Thanks. I agree that copying data doesn't cause computation matter, from my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd question, the answer is **NO**.

From the [OpenCV's doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6), `Mat Mat::operator()(const Rect& roi) const` will make a new header. So releasing the `sourceMat` will not affect `m`.